# How to find a word and delete it with the following line

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, gawk

I've been using `awk` in an `Expect` script to edit a text file that contains information about a switch, so far the text file looks like this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce 
  BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6 
  N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL) Gig 1/0/1 134 
  LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11 
  Arquitectura_Salones Gig 1/0/9 129 
  CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4 
  Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3 
  ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10 
  ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7 
  Ingenieria_Posgrado --More-- 
  Device ID Local Intrfce 
  Gig 1/0/8 134 
  Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2 
  Electronica_Edif_3 Gig 1/0/5 127 
  Barragan_3750>exit Connection closed by foreign host. 
  ]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```

As the script handles with multiple lines output, te label `--More--` is printed in the text file, as well the column name `Device ID Local Intrfce` is printed twice.

I want the file to look like this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce 
  BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6 
  N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL) Gig 1/0/1 134 
  LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11 
  Arquitectura_Salones Gig 1/0/9 129 
  CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4 
  Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3 
  ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10 
  ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7 
  Ingenieria_Posgrado Gig 1/0/8 134 
  Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2 
  Electronica_Edif_3 Gig 1/0/5 127 
  Barragan_3750>exit Connection closed by foreign host. 
  ]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```

I Know how to find a specific word, but it could be in any column because that depends on terminal length.

just to recap, I want to find the word --More-- and delete it with the following line.

Any help?

Thanks.

Update:

this did the work: `sed '/--More--/{N;N; s/--More--.*\n[ \t]*//}'`
in the expect script the syntaxis is:

```
send -- "sed '/--More--/{N;N; s/--More--.*\\n\[ \\t\]*//}' TablaCDP.dat > CDPyPuerto.dat \r"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/--More--/{s///;n;d;}'
```

The `awk` equivalent:

```
awk 'sub(/--More--/, "") {print; getline; next}; {print}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good approach, but I need to keep the word Ingenieria_Posgrado following by Gig 1/0/8 134  in the same line. With this solution, the whole line is deleted.

Comment: @CesarAlejandroVillegasYepez see if `sed '/--More--/{N;N; s/--More--.*\n[ \t]*//}'` helps..

Comment: It worked perfectly @Sundeep thanks a lot , I just update the post.

Comment: @CesarAlejandroVillegasYepez, sorry the `N` should have been a `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl can do it too:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ = "" if($. > 1 and $_ =~ /Device ID Local Intrfce/); $_ =~ s/--More--//;'  input.txt   
Device ID Local Intrfce 
  BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6 
  N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL) Gig 1/0/1 134 
  LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11 
  Arquitectura_Salones Gig 1/0/9 129 
  CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4 
  Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3 
  ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10 
  ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7 
  Ingenieria_Posgrado  
  Gig 1/0/8 134 
  Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2 
  Electronica_Edif_3 Gig 1/0/5 127 
  Barragan_3750>exit Connection closed by foreign host. 
  ]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```